# Obter CCO de e-mail C#

Tags: c#

possuo um sistema que verifica e-mails, e possuo o seguinte código onde ele busca o destinatário ou o campo "com cópia":

```
if (client.GetMessage(i).Headers.To != null)
{
    var msgTemp = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.To.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address.Contains("exemplo"));
    emailDestinatario = msgTemp != null ? msgTemp.Address.ToString() : "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailDestinatario))
    {
        msgTemp = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.Cc.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address.Contains("exemplo"));
        emailDestinatario = msgTemp != null ? msgTemp.Address.ToString() : "";
    }
}
```

Porém, preciso obter o CCO, é possível obter isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Verifique o e-mail possui a propriedade BCC (Cópia oculta).

```
 var listaCCO = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.BCC;
```

Fonte:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.bcc.aspx